# Crashing [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:]

Tags: objective-c

The application is crashing below I don't know it seems like apple bug.. if any one faced the same problem please update me

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates: —>// crashing here
    ^{
        if (indexToInsertAt == count)
        {
            // Add cell at end of list
            [self.restaurantList addObject:cellData];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexToInsertAt
                                                         inSection:0];
            [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
        }
        else
        {
            // Insert cell
            [self.restaurantList insertObject:cellData
                                      atIndex:indexToInsertAt];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexToInsertAt
                                                         inSection:0];
            [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
        }
    }
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }];
```

crash log are here:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
SIGABRT ABORT at 0x3baff1f0
 raw
0
libsystem_kernel.dylib  
__pthread_kill + 8
10
Foundation  
-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
11
UIKit   
__45-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke + 1206
12
UIKit   
-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 938
13
UIKit   
-[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 156
14
UIKit   
-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 380
15
QuartzCore  
-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
16
QuartzCore  
CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
17
UIKit   
-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 550
18
UIKit   
-[UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 170
```

crash is happening rearly please help me out

thanks in advance....

Comment: dose any faced the same problem ? please help if anyone know the solution

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i faced the same issue...